# Use ternary operator to attribute a current date to a variable if passed null

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, logical-operators

I'm trying to compare 2 dates in JS. If one of the dates is NULL or empty (fieldIdStart) I'd like to replace it by the current date.

I've got this far but it didn't work.
I can't tell what I'm missing.

```
function CompareDate(fieldIdStart, fieldIdEnd) {
            var today = new Date();
            var dateStart = (!$("#" + fieldIdStart).val()) ?  today.getDate().toString().concat((today.getMonth()+1).toString(), today.getFullYear().toString()) : $("#" + fieldIdStart).val();    
    (...)
    }
```

Comment: Which exactly is not working? Also share a working snippet demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Why do it in one line, break it up

Comment: You never use `fieldIdEnd`. Not very clear what you expect this code to do

Comment: _Use ternary operator to attribute a current date to a variable if passed null_ which variable ?

Comment: The ternary operator is meant to be used on simple `if/then` logic as a form of compacting syntax. When you start including long, compound statements in the branches, you defeat that purpose and should really just go back to a normal `if(){}else{}` syntax because readable code is always better than compact code.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
function CompareDate(fieldIdStart, fieldIdEnd) {
  const today = getToday();
  const dateStart = getDate(fieldIdStart) ? getDate(fieldIdStart) : today;
  const dateEnd = getDate(fieldIdEnd) ? getDate(fieldIdEnd) : today;
  return dateEnd - dateStart;
}

function getDate(fieldDate) {
  const date = $('#' + fieldDate).val();
  return date ? date : '';
}

function getToday() {
  const today = new Date();
  return today.getDate().toString().concat((today.getMonth() + 1).toString(), today.getFullYear().toString());
}
```